# Does Rust have an elegant way to manipulate values further when assigning a value from a block statement?

Tags: rust, instantiation

I am trying to declare a variable with expressions in a block.

```
let y = {
    let x = 3;
    x + 1
};
```

The code below equals 4. As I understand, the last element in the block cannot have a semicolon as that makes this expression a statement.

What if I want to manipulate the values further? For instance, what if I want to instantiate two variables and multiply them? Does Rust have an elegant way to handle this, or do I need to split this into many expressions?

Pseudocode:

```
//An attempt to multiply two instantiated values in a block
let y = {
    let z = 2;
    let x = 3;
    x + 1;
    x * z
};
```

Comment: Your "pseudocode" compiles (with a warning) so I'm not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the pseudocode is that `x` is immutable — it cannot be changed. To achieve the desired effect, you must make `x` mutable and it can be increased with `x += 1`, not `x + 1`:

```
let y = {
    let z = 2;
    let mut x = 3;
    x += 1;
    x * z
};
```

will return 8.